# Run single system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5, system-testing, ruby-on-rails-5.1

To run a single test in Rails, we normally do:

```
rails test TEST=test/system/invitation_test.rb
```

But that doesn't work with system tests. Neither do this work:

```
rails test:system TEST=test/system/invitation_test.rb
```

With both those commandos above, all system tests (files) are run.

So my question is, how can I run a single system test?

---

As a side note, to run (all) system tests in Rails, [you need to append](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-a-system-test)  `:system` to `test`.

```
rails test:system
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While `rails test` doesn't seem to work if you want to run your system tests (you need to append test with :system), if you only want to run a single test it *does* seem to work:

```
rails test test/system/my_little_test.rb
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about it before 